# Troubleshoot Kerberos pre-authentication failed logons

Tags: security, kerberos, login, windows-event-log

Once in a while we get a notification that an account triggered too many failed kerberos pre-authentication attempts.

This event contains the username and source machine. Here is an example:

```
Kerberos pre-authentication failed.

Account Information:
    Security ID:        S-1-5-21-18748694-320865252-1848988061-49003
    Account Name:       <account name>

Service Information:
    Service Name:       krbtgt/<domain>

Network Information:
    Client Address:     ::ffff:<ip address>
    Client Port:        60938

Additional Information:
    Ticket Options:     0x40810010
    Failure Code:       0x18
    Pre-Authentication Type:    2

Certificate Information:
    Certificate Issuer Name:        
    Certificate Serial Number:  
    Certificate Thumbprint:     

Certificate information is only provided if a certificate was used for pre-authentication.
```

'Additional Information' translated to human readable format:

Ticket Options:     0x40810010 => Forwardable, Renewable, Canonicalize, Renewable-ok

Failure Code:       0x18 => KDC_ERR_PREAUTH_FAILED | Pre-authentication information was invalid | The wrong password was provided.

Pre-Authentication Type:    2 => PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP | This type is normal for standard password authentication.

These events come in fast succession (50+ / sec).

Is it possible to find the source of the events e.g. software / script / service / ... ? And if so what would that process look like?